# BFS same way different result (python)

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

Problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/

Trying to figure out why calling the `bfs` function results in "correct" behavior according to the testcases, while just writing the plain code with no function call does not. It's literally the same code.

```
class Solution:

    def bfs(self, grid, queue):
       
        while len(queue) != 0:
            
            i, j = queue.pop(0)

            if i - 1 >= 0 and grid[i - 1][j] == "1":
                grid[i - 1][j] = "0"
                queue.append((i - 1, j))

            if i + 1 < len(grid) and grid[i + 1][j] == "1":
                grid[i + 1][j] = "0"
                queue.append((i + 1, j))

            if j - 1 >= 0 and grid[i][j - 1] == "1":
                grid[i][j - 1] = "0"
                queue.append((i, j - 1))

            if j + 1 < len(grid[i]) and grid[i][j + 1] == "1":
                grid[i][j + 1] = "0"
                queue.append((i, j + 1))

            
    def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:

        sol = 0

        for i in range(0, len(grid), 1):
            for j in range(0, len(grid[i]), 1):

                if grid[i][j] == "1":
                    sol += 1
            
                    queue = [(i, j)]

                    grid[i][j] = "0"
                    
# calling the function does different behavior
#                     self.bfs(grid, queue)
    
# as opposed to not calling the bfs function:           
#                     while len(queue) != 0:
#                         print(queue)
#                         i, j = queue.pop(0)

#                         if i - 1 >= 0 and grid[i - 1][j] == "1":
#                             grid[i - 1][j] = "0"
#                             queue.append((i - 1, j))

#                         if i + 1 < len(grid) and grid[i + 1][j] == "1":
#                             grid[i + 1][j] = "0"
#                             queue.append((i + 1, j))

#                         if j - 1 >= 0 and grid[i][j - 1] == "1":
#                             grid[i][j - 1] = "0"
#                             queue.append((i, j - 1))

#                         if j + 1 < len(grid[i]) and grid[i][j + 1] == "1":
#                             grid[i][j + 1] = "0"
#                             queue.append((i, j + 1))

        return sol
```

Testcase:

```
[["1","0","0","1","1","1","0","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],["1","0","0","1","1","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","0","1","0"],["0","0","0","1","1","1","1","0","1","0","1","1","0","0","0","0","1","0","1","0"],["0","0","0","1","1","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","1","1","0","0","1","0","0","1"],["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],["1","0","0","0","0","1","0","1","0","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","1"],["0","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1"],["0","0","0","1","0","1","0","0","1","1","0","1","0","1","1","0","1","1","1","0"],["0","0","0","0","1","0","0","1","1","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","1"],["0","0","1","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","0"],["1","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","1","0","1","0","1","0"],["0","1","0","0","0","1","0","1","0","1","1","0","1","1","1","0","1","1","0","0"],["1","1","0","1","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","1"],["0","1","0","0","1","1","1","0","0","0","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","0","0","0"],["0","0","1","1","1","0","0","0","1","1","0","0","0","1","0","1","0","0","0","0"],["1","0","0","1","0","1","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","1","0","1","1"],["1","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","1","0","0","0","0"],["0","1","1","0","0","0","1","1","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","1","1","1","0","0"],["0","1","0","0","0","0","1","1","0","0","1","0","1","0","0","1","0","0","1","1"],["0","0","0","0","0","0","1","1","1","1","0","1","0","0","0","1","1","0","0","0"]]
```

calling function returns the expected solution: 58
while not calling returns: 47

Comment: good catch , fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big picture view of your solution:

```
        for i in range(0, len(grid), 1):
            for j in range(0, len(grid[i]), 1):
                run BFS
```

If you write the BFS code right there, it messes up the variable `i` from that outer loop (also `j`, but that doesn't matter). If you instead call the function, that function has its own local variable `i` and doesn't mess up the loop's.